# stripe payment intent data metadata

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to pass metadata through a Stripe checkout session. Currently, I am trying to pass it via payment_intent_data.metadata, as suggested in Stripe's documentation, but I am getting a 500 error exception
:
"Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException", message
:
"Invalid object". But I seem to be following the suggested configuration on Stripe's docs, so I'm at a standstill.

StripeController.php

```php
    public function handle_checkout(Request $request)
    {
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env("STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY"));

        $req_content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $line_items = []; 

        $email = "";

        foreach($req_content as $key => $val) {
            $new_line_item = [
                'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => $val["product_item"]["name"],
                ],
                'unit_amount' => $val["product_item"]["price"] * 100,
                ],
                'quantity' => $val["cart_item"]["quantity"]
            ];
            
            $email = $val["user_email"];

            array_push($line_items, $new_line_item);
        }

        $checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
            'shipping_address_collection' => ['allowed_countries' => ['US']],
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            "customer_email" => $email,
            'line_items' => $line_items,
            'payment_intent_data' => [ 
                 ## Here, I am just putting "AAA" for testing
                'metadata' => "AAA"
            ],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => 'my success url ...',
            'cancel_url' => 'my cancel url...',
          ]);
     
        return $checkout_session->url; 
    }
```

If I don't add

```php
'payment_intent_data' => [ 
                 ## Here, I am just putting "AAA" for testing
                'metadata' => "AAA"
            ],
```

then it works. But I want to pass metadata through the checkout process and get it on payment_intent.succeeded.

Thoughts?

Comment: 'payment_intent_data.metadata' => "AAA", doesn't work either.

Comment: SOLUTION:             'payment_intent_data' => [ 
                   'metadata' => [ 
                            "AAA" => "BBB"
                   ]
            ],

Comment: `metadata` contains key-value pair(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
        'payment_intent_data' => [ 
               'metadata' => [ 
                        "AAA" => "BBB"
               ]
        ],
```

> > THIS WORKS